# Nginx Proxy pass returns 50x error

Tags: nginx, proxypass

How can I use or configure `proxy_pass` in NGINX in order to display my react application when someone visits my website?

Below you can read the configuration I am using, but it is not working as I expect and redirecting to website.com:3000.

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  dummyReactSite.com;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/; 
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: connect() to 127.0.0.1:3000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 97.102.226.107, server: dummyReactSite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", that client ip is not the ip of the server, may be the ip of the cloudflare though

Comment: That's easy enough to fix. See the linked post above for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It was a fault of the OS (cent7) and SELinux permissioning,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx
had more information